# Predicting results of a game (TicTacToe), with players using fixed strategies

Tags: probability, problem-solving, mathematical-modeling

How would you predict the distribution of wins/losses/ties for two computer players in a game of [TicTacToe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) Where each player has a fixed strategy for playing?

In my situation both players are using the same strategy which is as follows:

1) If there is a winning move, go there.

2) Else, If there is a winning move for the opponent, go there (stop the opponent from winning.)

3) Else, choose a remaining open move at random (from a uniform distribution).

Player-1 always goes first, and Player-2 second.

After doing some simulations with this strategy I got the following results:
For 100,000 simulated games:

Ties: 51,446 (51.45%)

Player-1 wins: 31,011 (31.01%)

Player-2 wins: 17,543 (17.54%)

So how would one begin to model this? My instinct would be to use Markov chains.

Any resources for where to look, or study up on would also be very helpful.

Comment: You should first make this a bit more precise:
By "winning move" you mean a move that lets you win right away or a move that assures you will eventually win if both player use an optimal strategy from that point on? For example assume you have $\begin{matrix} N &o & N \\N &x & N \\N &N &N\end{matrix}$ and $x$ moves, then the upper left corner is considered a winning move?

Depending on the answer to the above, what if there are more "winning moves"?

Comment: By "winning move", I mean that you will win immediately. The strategy is simple on purpose as I originally designed it as a baseline model to test against an AI using reinforcement learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could definitely use a Markov chain for this, but given that there is no possibility of repeating a position in Tic Tac Toe, this is a bit overkill - elementary techniques work just fine for this sort of thing, since the answer is just successively taking weighted averages of a bunch of probabilities. For instance, if you had this position (with X to move):
$$\begin{array}{ccc}X & O  & X\\
O & * & *\\
*&* & *\\
\end{array}$$
where the $*$'s are empty spaces, you would find that the probability of winning/losing/drawing are just the average of the respective probabilities of each of the $5$ positions $X$ might randomly choose - which, could each be computed the same way. There are not so many positions, at least in computational terms, so just programming a computer to run this calculation is not so intensive, as long as you save the results of each computation (i.e. use memoization).

In concrete terms, the algorithm to compute this quantity is simply: let $L$ represent the current board state. First, check if someone has won in $L$ or if a draw has been reached - the probability will be either $0$ or $1$ in these cases. If not, compute every move that the player whose turn it is might reasonably make (i.e. if they can win, a winning move. If not, but their opponent could win, a move to block that. If not, any legal move). Compute the probabilities of winning from those states and take their average. Save the result. Note that this method will never touch unreachable states.

In Mathematica, this is implemented as follows - one can modify the `ReasonableMoves` function for other strategies - or write this in other languages. Since it seems like you have a working simulation already (unless you did 100,000 trials by hand), you could probably easily modify it to give an exact answer instead of an approximation, as long as your language has some easy way to support exact rational arithmetic and an associative container for memoizing positions.

```
IsWinForPlayer[p_, l_] := With[{occupied = Map[# == p &, l, {2}]},
   Or[Or @@ (And @@ # & /@ occupied), 
    Or @@ (And @@ # & /@ Transpose[occupied]), 
    occupied[[1, 1]] && occupied[[2, 2]] && occupied[[3, 3]], 
    occupied[[1, 3]] && occupied[[2, 2]] && occupied[[3, 1]]]];
IsDraw[l_] := Plus @@ (Plus @@ Map[Abs, l, {2}]) == 9;
WhoseTurn[l_] := If[Plus @@ (Plus @@ l) == 0, 1, -1];
EmptyPositions[l_] := Position[l, 0, {2}];
ReasonableMoves[l_] := 
  Module[{empty, player, possible, winning, opponentWin},
   empty = EmptyPositions[l];
   player = WhoseTurn[l];
   possible = ReplacePart[l, # -> player] & /@ empty;
   winning = Select[possible, IsWinForPlayer[player, #] &];
   If[Length[winning] > 0, winning];
   opponentWin = 
    Select[empty, 
     IsWinForPlayer[-player, ReplacePart[l, # -> -player]] &];
   If[Length[opponentWin] > 0, 
    Return[ReplacePart[l, # -> player] & /@ opponentWin]];
   possible
   ];
StartingPosition = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
ProbabilityOfWin[p_, l_] := 
  ProbabilityOfWin[p, l] = 
   Which[IsWinForPlayer[p, l], 1, IsWinForPlayer[-p, l] || IsDraw[l], 
    0, True, Mean[ProbabilityOfWin[p, #] & /@ ReasonableMoves[l]]];
```

It gives a probability of $347/1680$ for the first player winning and $169/1680$ for the second player and only takes about 1 second of computation for each on my laptop (in Mathematica - a language not known for speed). These numbers seem a lot lower than your simulation (which should have been very accurate for the number of trials) - so there might be some discrepancy in what the actual strategy used was - but the method generalizes to any strategy. This method can also be modified to find the optimal strategy by instead computing, for each position, whether it is a win, draw, or loss under optimal play by looking at whether each legal move from that position is a win, draw, or loss.

Comment: This is much better than the Markov chain approach, I agree.  I shouldn't right answers before breakfast.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly solve the problem using Markov chains.  The Wikipedia article on [absorbing Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) tells you all the math you need to know.

A state is absorbing if once the chain enters that state, it never leaves.  In tic-tac-toe, there are $3$ absorbing states: X wins, O wins, tie.

The biggest problem is the matrix is large.  If we just say that every cell on the board is either X, O, or blank, we have $3^9=19,683$ possibilities.  Of course, some of these correspond to one the of the absorbing states, but the real problem is that most of them represent impossible positions.  We need to take into account that there must be same number of X's and O's, or one more X than than O's.  If I haven't made a mistake, there are $6045$ legal positions.  Again, it's a bit less than this, since some positions correspond to absorbing states.

Depending on how much RAM you have, this should be doable.  If not, you can substantially, reduce the size of the matrix by taking advantage of symmetry.  There are $8$ symmetries of a square, so each position is equivalent to up to $7$ others.  You can therefore reduce the size of the matrix by a factor close to $8$.  The drawback to this approach is that computing the transition matrix becomes more complicated.  For each state, and for each transition from that state, you have to determine the canonical form of the successor state.